Removing references to a GPG error, repository, and key for uninstalled app
Ubuntu 22.04.5 LTS server
sudo apt-get update yields:
W: GPG error: https://download.webmin.com/download/repository sarge Release: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY D97A3AE911F63C51```
E: The repository 'https://download.webmin.com/download/repository sarge Release' is not signed.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.

Webmin has been UNINSTALLED.
No other errors.
Apparently there is a reference to a repository that is no longer needed? I would think this makes the signature and pubkey moot.
gpg --list-keys returns null.
How do I eliminate these messages?
I would like to re-install webmin once this issue is resolved.
Thank you for all constructive input!
